# Add some custom Events/Linstener to Android View like ListView

Tags: java, android

*Hello, 
I need to simulate some behaviors that are present on iOS for a ListView like for example detect when a header or footer is Displayed or when an item is being  added or removed . 
In other hand I want to have an equivalent to Delegate concept on ios for my android views so I can register my views to detect more events even some custom events. 
Thanks for your reply 
Have a good day*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for solutions I found that the simplest way to do this was to make my Custom view/Listener/Events and override the methods to detect the behaviours I need.